# Why a decaying dark matter?

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, dark-matter

I'm reading some papers ([model](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.12550), [exp](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.09331) and [model](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.10795)) that are dealing with decaying models of DM, why is it interesting? What are the signatures that this type of model can give to observe DM?

I am interested in general on the reasoning behind the choice of a decaying dark matter. Why is that interesting to study? Is there any smoking gun experiment that could detect decaying DM?

Comment: What kind of decaying models? Which papers?

Comment: @NiharKarve I edited the question adding some of the papers. But I am interested in general on the reasoning behind the choice of a decaying dark matter. Why is that interesting to study? Is there any smoking gun experiment that could detect decaying DM?

Answer (score 1):

This is just my personal view and I am happy for another answer to supersede mine. Given the manageable number of papers looking in this direction I think classifying it as "interesting" would need a discussion about the semantics ;)  Since the nature of dark matter remains an open question, it is well worth to think and re-think existing bounds and assumptions. Perhaps one of these lines of reasoning open the path to exactly that avenue which eventually proves to be the one to solve the mystery - who is to say. In that context it makes sense to think about how stable dark matter really needs to be, what the bounds are, and to think about the observational consequeces.

Depending on the decay mechanism and in particular the decay products, this becomes a channel that one can search for at least in principle using indirect dark matter searches (from air Cherenkov telescopes and gamma ray satellites to neutrino detectors). Though from what I can see, I doubt that this would be a discovery channel, as the signal would be very weak and spread across all redshifts. Interestingly, whereas a vanilla (e.g. WIMP) annihilation signal in indirect searches would scale as the density of dark matter squared, for decaying dark matter, it would scale only linearly with density.

Answer (score 1):

It's also interesting because it alleviates the $\sigma_8$ tension in cosmology